# Typescript / Angular 7: How can I iterate over Object matching my Interface with Object.keys?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, interface, angular7

I am pretty new to Javascript and Typescript/Angular..

I am getting data / game stats from a website to make my own stats app. I have created an Interface with defined Key/Values to match the data that I want to show on my template.

The API's response that I wish to show is in the form of nested objects. Because of this, I am using Object.keys() in order to iterate through the objects, and show the result on my HTML template.

I am able to show JSON of the specific nested Object just fine. My problem is: it is showing the ENTIRE Key/Values of that Object, and not the specific key values I have defined in my Interface.

Within my HTML, I am looping through my Interface called lifeTimeStat `Object.keys(lifeTimeStat)` - (also please see below for full html)

Seeing as how I need to iterate through an Object, I attempted to make my lifeTimeStat Interface an object..  Like this:

```
`export class CombatListComponent implements OnInit {

constructor(public combatService: CombatService) { }

lifeTimeStats: lifeTimeStat = {
headshotKills: null,
             kills: null,
             longestKill: null, 
             maxKillStreaks: null,
             dailyKills: null,
             weeklyKills: null,
             damageDealt: null,
             roadKills: null,
             teamKills: null,
              vehicleDestroys: null,
              suicides: null,
              roundMostKills: null,
              dBNOs: null,
              assists: null
  } 


ngOnInit() {
this.combatService.getCombat().subscribe(data => {this.lifeTimeStats = 
data} );  
}
}
```

`

But of course, however, I am getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined` .. So it seems I am not making my Interface into an Object the right way..

The only way that I can get the JSON to show in my HTML is if I instead define
`Object = Object` instead of that crappy attempt of turning my Interface into an object..  Argh. `Object = Object` will just show the entire Object and not the specific shape of my Interface..

HTML: combat-list.component.html

`<div *ngFor="let key of Object.keys(lifeTimeStat)">    {{ lifeTimeStats[key].attributes.gameModeStats.solo| json }}  </div> <br>`

Service Component: combat.service.ts

```
`@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CombatService {
getCombat():Observable<lifeTimeStat> {

return this.http.get<lifeTimeStat>(this.configUrl,  { observe:'body',   
responseType: 'json', headers: getHeaders });    

}`
```

Interface:

```
    `export interface lifeTimeStat {


            headshotKills: number,
             kills: number,
             longestKill: number, 
             maxKillStreaks: number,
             dailyKills: number,
             weeklyKills: number,
             damageDealt: number,
             roadKills: number,
             teamKills: number,
              vehicleDestroys: number,
              suicides: number,
              roundMostKills: number,
              dBNOs: number,
              assists: number,



}  `
```

I just want to show the selected data as I have defined in my Interface. I've been googling / searching on SO for many hours over the course of two, almost three days :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this syntax should work:

```
Object
  .keys({ a: 1, b: 2 })
  .map(key => console.log(key));
```

If not, why don't you assign the array to a variable and iterate over the variable?

In any case, you can use this nice helper to preserve types and iterate over both keys and values:

```
const testObject = {
  completed: true,
  score: 129.1,
  description: 'none',
};

entries(testObject)
 .map(([key, value]) => console.log(`Key is ${key}, value is ${value}`));

function entries<K>(object: K)  {
    return (Object.keys(object) as (keyof K)[])
        .filter((key) => object[key] !== undefined && object[key] !== null)
        .map(
            key => ([
                key,
                object[key],
            ] as [keyof K, Required<K>[keyof K]]),
    );
}

type Required<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]-?: T[P];
};
```

Or for your case:

```
const keyValuePairs = entries(lifeTimeStat);

...

<div *ngFor="const [key, value] of keyValuePairs">    {{ value.attributes.gameModeStats.solo| json }}  </div> <br>
```

Comment: Interesting, I will try this and come back. Thanks a lot :)